# How to check multiple linear regression result per parameter (sklearn model)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, statistics

I'm using default multiple linear regression on sklearn

```
from sklearn import linear_model

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model = regr.fit(X, y)
predictions = model.predict(X)
```

When I call `prediction`, here's the result

```
ApplicationID
2019XXX68954    0.700000
2020XXX59500    0.642747
2020XXX52277    0.405954
```

What I want

```
ApplicationID   Variable1       Variable2        Score
2019XXX68954     0.200000        0.500000     0.700000
2020XXX59500     ........        ........     0.642747
2020XXX52277     ........        ........     0.405954
```

What I mean by `Variable1` and  `Variable2` is partial score that generated by coefficient time constanta in this multiple regressesion, so I can see which variable that give maximal contribution to the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can element-wise multiply the `model.coef_` with your `X`:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=10, n_features=3, bias=0.9, random_state=51)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)

# Form the dataframe
data = X * model.coef_
columns=[f"Variable{j}" for j, _ in enumerate(model.coef_, start=1)]

result = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

# put the intercept, too
result.insert(0, "Variable0", model.intercept_)
```

to get

```
>>> result

   Variable0   Variable1  Variable2   Variable3
0        0.9  -17.538372   4.172825  108.040511
1        0.9  156.267901 -18.817702  -50.471148
2        0.9  -21.506439 -40.510528  -30.320019
3        0.9  110.403966  40.281776   31.840830
4        0.9  -41.648604  -3.187173   71.067339
5        0.9  -76.860056  27.791395  -48.228522
6        0.9  -82.160185   3.718984   -4.145350
7        0.9   17.780070 -49.726577  -90.128025
8        0.9   55.302550  63.892190   44.852370
9        0.9   -6.689355 -44.186517  -87.087998
```

The sanity check is that sum of each row of `result` should be equal to model's prediction per sample:

```
>>> np.allclose(model.predict(X), result.sum(axis=1))
True
```